# Categorical Image of a map out of a co-product

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Suppose $(A\sqcup B,i_A:A\to A\sqcup B,i_B:B\to A\sqcup B)$ is a co-product of $A$ and $B$ in an arbitrary abelian category $\mathcal{A}$.

For any object $T\in \mathcal{A}$, any map $f:A\sqcup B\to T$ is fully characterized (by the universal property of co-products) by the maps $fi_A$ and $fi_B$. I also know that any map $f$ in any abelian category is uniquely (up to unique isomorphism) fully characterized by its decomposition through its image object $\text{Im}(f)$.

Suppose I know what $\text{Im}(fi_A)$ and $\text{Im}(fi_B)$ are. Then, how can I use this to find $\text{Im}(f)$?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{Im}$? Are we assuming the category of sets, or some other concrete category?

Comment: Im $f$ is indeed the image of $f$ defined in an arbitrary abelian category as the kernel of the cokernel map of $f$. I have added this to the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of [subobjects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject), $\mathrm{Im}(f)\hookrightarrow T$ is the smallest subobject of $T$ containing both $\mathrm{Im}(fi_A)\hookrightarrow T$ and $\mathrm{Im}(fi_B)\hookrightarrow T$, i.e. it is their join in the subobject lattice of $T$. There is no reason to expect any more concrete statement in this generality. In concrete examples, there may be concrete characterizations, e.g. in $\mathcal{A}=\mathrm{Mod}(R)$, subobjects are identified with submodules and their join is the usual sum.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you :))